# UIBarButtonItem offset

Tags: iphone, uibarbuttonitem

you can see the distance to the left of the button? How to remove this distance?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a spacer to the left of the button, something like:

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButtonItem = ....;

UIBarButtonItem *spacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
spacer.width = -5; 

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = @[ spacer, backButtonItem ];
```

Comment: Can it be done in XCode? When setting width to -5 it tells me that it's not a valid value.

Comment: Thx a lot for the answer, by the way, can it be done via [UIBarButtonItem appearance] to make **every** flexible space have such width?